# Are these Portal challenges impossible?

Tags: portal

I am playing *Portal: Still Alive* on XBox 360. In the challenge maps, there are advanced levels for chambers 13-18 named like "14: Advanced" and just like the standard chambers, they have medal challenges in least portals, fastest time, and least footsteps.

The targets for these challenges appear to be *exactly* the same targets as their standard counterparts. For example, *Test Chamber 13: least portals* challenge gives bronze at 9 portals, silver at 5, and gold at 4. *13: Advanced* also has bronze at 9 portals, silver at 5, and (presumably) gold at 4 even though the chamber is modified.

Also, from what I can gather online, the Orange Box version of the same game didn't have medal challenges for the advanced chambers at all (and still had the same medal challenges for the standard chambers).

These facts cause me to believe that the appearance of medal challenges for 13-18 advanced chambers was merely a oversight in the *Portal: Still Alive* version of the game.

Are these medal challenges impossible as I suspect?

Comment: @kotekzot Developer interviews or commentary elsewhere that indicate one way or the other? Who knows, but just so: somebody might know. Asking is a way of finding out if anyone knows.

Comment: @kotekzot Often game developers are not extremely secretive about the development of a game. In Portal: Still Alive there is commentary built into the game that tells about the how the 2-portal solution for Testchamber 13 was left in after a playtester discovered it. I assume advanced medal challenges were unintentional, but I don't know. Someone else might know. What's the harm in asking?

Comment: Seems like the greater internet doesn't know based on [16: Advanced is impossible](http://www.xbox360achievements.org/forum/showthread.php?t=117982) and [another for the same](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/950903-portal-still-alive/48940706). However, [17: Advanced *is* possible](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BM5dQj-v100)

Comment: @ken.ganong That video for 17 Advanced is played on PC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the Advanced Chamber gold medal challenges in Portal are possible. Below are videos from Carrot Helper showing the Least Portals, Least Steps, and Least Time challenges being completed.

Answer (score -3):

If they would be impossible they won't be created.

Search up for speed runners, they know how to do this.
Just if you want to learn how to speed run, but it is to hard. Like they use bugs, and other stuff. But now more about your question.

They are just hard to beat and you have to think for a long time.

If they would be impossible they won't be created.

Here's Advanced Test Chamber 13, for example, in spoilers:

> [This video shows you how it works](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0kQzgBykO4M)

Comment: Generally, we prefer answers to answer the question directly.  Yeah, they're not impossible, but that information isn't really useful if you don't go more in depth on how to go about accomplishing it.

Comment: I just did that now, before you told me. But you are cinda helping me but annoying me. Maybe I would came to this idea in some minutes or seconds.
This site should help other people, and you should learn how to help other peoples. Like how you help them very good and ect. and if you find your errors you learn.

You can still ask someone but you are doing this like a rocket hitting in a wall making a hole and telling me something.

Comment: We expect quality here at Arqade.  If you show effort in your posts, you'll do fine.  If you don't like criticism, well, this isn't the place for you, then.  One thing that might help is to ensure your post has all the info you want it to before posting.  Quality over quantity.

Comment: This answer is false. The video shown here doesn't achieve the portal medal challenge (it uses 15 portals though the bronze medal is 9 portals). This in no way indicates that the medal challenges on advanced maps are possible.